# read csv is concating last colum of first row with first column of second row in php

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I have a csv file like this
[image]

i have used the following code.

```
     $filename=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    //$err_upTmpName = 'testfile.csv';


        if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
            return FALSE;

        $header = array('id','name','qty','rate');
        $data = array();

$r = 1;
$r1=0;
$rw=0;
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);


           for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
               if ($r <= 4) {

               } else {
                   $r = 1;

                   $a[$r1] = $s;
                   $r1++;
               }
               $s[] = $data[$c];
               $r++;
           }

       $rw++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

var_dump($a);
```

am getting the output as

> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "pppp" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOLuc.png)=> string(3)
>   "kjj" [2]=> string(3) "rrr" [3]=> string(7) "sss a33" } [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOLuc.png)=> array(8)
>   { [0]=> string(4) "pppp" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOLuc.png)=> string(3) "kjj" [2]=> string(3) "rrr"
>   [3]=> string(7) "sss a33" [4]=> string(3) "200" [5]=> string(2) "50"
>   [6]=> string(6) "555 zz" [7]=> string(2) "33" } }

Here am getting first row 3rd column value as sss 333.
But i need as ss.
Also 2nd row in the array is again the first row.
I need the output like

> [{ppp,kjj,rrr,sss},{a33,200,50,555},{zz,33,44,44}]

Please help me.

Comment: That looks like horrible code. Why don't you use some library that handles parsing the CSV file into an array for you?

Comment: Without the actual csv it is hard to test but there is a note in PHP documentation
**Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: your expected output is not valid format. can you clarify more what you actually looking for? just getting last column value of 1st row and first column value of 2nd row? or like to build a json format output?